# $.mobile.changePage doesn't load the CSS

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, mobile

This is a very weird situation with ajax. I have a login page which calls the mainpage via ajax, like this:

```
 // Function to call WCF  Service - Infrastructure       
    function CallService() {
        $.ajax({
            type: Type, //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
            url: Url, // Location of the service
            data: Data, //Data sent to server
            contentType: ContentType, // content type sent to server
            dataType: DataType, //Expected data format from server
            processdata: ProcessData, //True or False
            success: function (msg) {//On Successfull service call
                ServiceSucceeded(msg);
            },
            error: ServiceFailed// When Service call fails
        });
    }

    function ServiceSucceeded(result) {

        if (DataType == "json") {
            var resultText = result;
            if (resultText.result == "True") {
                $.mobile.changePage("MainMenu.aspx",{ transition: "slideup" });
            }
            else {
                //Show Error Message
            }
        }
    }
```

In every page I have a reference to an js called "general.js" which contains the following code:

```
function processMenu(menuOptions) {
var options = menuOptions.split('');
var currentOptions = '1234567'.split('')

for (i = 0; i < currentOptions.length; i++) {
    var index = (i + 1) + '';
    if (options.indexOf(index) < 0) {
        var op = $('#op' + currentOptions[i]);
        op.attr('disabled', true);
        op.addClass('btndisabled');
        $(op).live("click", function (event) {
            //do stuff
            event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default link behaviour
        });
    }
}
```

}

This code verifies some numbered controls and enable a CSS called "btndisabled" if it's requiered

The "btndisabled" CSS is:

```
.btndisabled{    
    background-color: rgb(236,233,216);
    color: #CCC;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Ok the situation is, when I use

```
$.mobile.changePage("MainMenu.aspx?",{ transition: "slideup" });
```

The Login.aspx content changes to the MainMenu.aspx content and the js:

```
op.attr('disabled', true);
op.addClass('btndisabled');
$(op).live("click", function (event) {
    //do stuff
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default link behaviour
});
```

is executed, the CSS is not applied BUT the "event.preventDefault" is executed. I need to apply the CSS but I don't what is wrong. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Watching the behaviour of the object on postback and in ajax call I realized something quite intersting, but I don't know what to think about it.

*On Postback*

[image]

Look at the HTMLAnchorElement

*Ajax*

[image]

If the DOM has not loaded the anchor object, HOW IS POSSIBLE TO ASSIGN THE event.preventDefault()???

This is crazy...

Comment: Where's the CSS on this question? I mean, where's the call?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9345637/why-do-elements-loaded-with-ajax-exhibit-no-jquery-mobile-css

Comment: the CSS is a reference in every page

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is probably on the jQuery Mobile forum itself:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/mobile-css-gets-lost-after-using-ajax-to-update-content

Comment: Well, I'll be honest! I QUIT!!... I fixed the situation doing a postback from the login page. Thanks for your time on this MelaciaUK